# How to make arch specific decision in Ansible playbooks?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am trying to use Ansible playbooks to run a multi-arch cluster. Now, to do that I need to make arch specific decisions. Is there any ansible module that can help me do that? Or is there any way where I can know the arch and use that in "when" conditional statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `debug` module to display your targets' facts and select the one that suits you best for your conditionals.

`ansible_architecture` for a start. `ansible_os_family`, `ansible_distribution`... Whatever works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Any idea what is the difference between ansible_architecture and ansbile_machine, they both look similar and confusing at the same time!

Comment: The code is not secret https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts.py

Comment: Got it! Can do that.